# Typescript: Property 'decoded' does not exists on type Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, typescript, request

I have this code in javascript:

```
if (token) {

    // verifies secret and checks exp
    jwt.verify(token, Config.Secret, function(err, decoded) {      
      if (err) {
        return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' });    
      } else {
        // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
        req.decoded = decoded;    
        next();
      }
    });

  } else {

    // if there is no token
    // return an error
    return res.status(403).send({ 
        success: false, 
        message: 'No token provided.' 
    });

  }
```

Want to rewrite it to typescript but getting an error `Property decoded does not exists on type Request`.

Any ideas how to solve that?

Comment: Do you have a type definition for `Request`?

Comment: @VadimMacagon yes it is coming from `express` `import {Request, Response} from "express";`

Comment: I see no `decoded` field in [express.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/express/express.d.ts), is it a field you've added yourself?

Comment: @VadimMacagon actually yes it is custom field. Oh what is the best way to do then?

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to make a new class extending Request you may access request as an object like:

```
req['decoded'] = decoded;
```

If it stills throws at you you may have to cast req as an object (typescript):

```
(<Object>req)['decoded'] = decoded;
```

You may even cast req to type any and access decoded as property (typescript):

```
(<any>req).decoded = decoded;
```

Answer (score 4):

You will need to use declaration merging to add type definitions for custom `Request` fields. To do so create a `.d.ts` file that looks like this:

```
declare module Express {
  export interface Request {
    decoded: string;
    // etc.
  }
}
```

And add it to your compilation context so the compiler merges the type definitions with the ones in `express.d.ts`.

Comment: this is a very fuzzy (though common approach). I would not recommend it and it's definitely not the best way to do it.

Comment: I would recommend this approach to all who come here in seek of the true answer, as it is the only one on this page that truly works.

Answer (score 1):

I would not merge interfaces from modules with the same name even if it's possible. I would rather make a new custom interface, which you can even declare in the very same file you are using it. (otherwise, just export it)

```
import {Request, Response} from "express";

interface CustomRequest extends Request {
    decoded: string;
}
```

This is much more cleaner and moreover it's closer to OOP.

Comment: This approach will just lead to chasing more type errors, e.g., error `TS2345: Argument of type '(req: CustomRequest, res: Response) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandlerParams'.
  Type '(req: CustomRequest, res: Response) => void' is not assignable to type '(RequestHandler | ErrorRequestHandler)[]'.
    Property 'push' is missing in type '(req: CustomRequest, res: Response) => void'.`

Comment: Can you provide a snippet where you had this problem? I never had problems on extending those standard interfaces of express. I want to understand 1. your issue and 2. the downvote. You seem to work with the wrong type...

Answer (score 1):

That error mean that the original [`Request`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts#L181) type from express don't any field with that name.

You have two options to solve this problem, the first one as [Vadim Macagon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35253217/4423322) pointed out, you can create a declaration module file and add your custom field, doing so that field will be avaliable on every Request.

```
declare module Express {
  export interface Request {
    decoded: string;
    // etc.
  }
}
```

---

Option two you can create a custom interface that extends the original Request and add your decoded field.

```
export default interface ICustomRequest extends Request {
  token: string;
}
```

and then in your code you

```
app.post('/', function (req: ICustomRequest, res) {
  req.decoded = decoded; // No errors here
});
```

The first solution you're "adding" the custom field to the `Request`, and the second you're add your field and extending from Request.

In your case I would use the first solution to avoid writing ICustomRequest (or whatever name you choose) every time that you have to use that `decoded` field from your request, the files `.d.ts` don't need to be imported in your code so you can just create the file and it's done.

Answer (score 0):

my 'decoded' was just user_id string and i solved this problem like this:

```
req.body.decoded = decoded;    
next();
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue, I followed the solution in the previous comments and this repo and I still had the same issue. After doing more digging it seems like it's a bug with ts-node.

To solve this you need to run your server with a --files flag

So if you normally run your server ts-node ./src/server.ts or nodemon ./src/server.ts Change it to ts-node --files ./src/server.ts or nodemon --files ./src/server.ts

After that, I was able to get rid of both the VScode errors and errors while starting the server.